# Ошибка ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Не могу понять, что не так? Без `for` оно работает а с ним нет.

```
public class isEven {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int [] r = new int [20] ;
        int [] k = new int[20] ;

        r[0]= 0;
        k[0] =3;

           int l= 1 ;
           int o =0 ;

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i=i+3){

           r[l] = k[o] + 2;
           k[l] = r[l] + 3;

          l++;
          o++;

    }      
}
```

выбивает такую ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   20    at isEven.main(isEven.java:17)

Comment: очевидно что проблема в `int l= 1 ;`

Comment: Перевожу: индекс 20 вышел за границы размерности массива.

Comment: очевидно, что при последней итерации массива l = 20, а индексы массива находятся в диапазоне 0 - 19 (индексы идут с 0, а не 1), в результате вы получаете ошибку "выход за пределы диапазона", потому что индекса 20 в массиве уже нет.

Answer (score 1):

Цикл повторяется 60 раз и поэтому значения ваших переменных l и o становятся больше чем 20. Это значит что в при какомто из повторений вы пытаетесь из массива размером 20 вытянуть переменную с индексом 21, которой у вас нет. Поэтому у вас программа и не работает с циклом for.